# XSL value-of doesn't seem to get value from the xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, value-of

I have an xml file which contains following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mods xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"  
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <titleInfo><title>A-Title-01</title></titleInfo>
</mods>
```

And an XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="titleInfo/title"/></p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is I don't get the title value in the xHTML. I could only see

### Description

Hello

But If I remove default namespace from the xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mods xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"  
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <titleInfo><title>A-Title-01</title></titleInfo>
</mods>
```

and change the style sheet's match to `<xsl:template match="/mods">` I can see the title value.

But I can not remove the default namespace from the xml because xml is generated by a form and it won't work if I remove the default namespace. I don't even have a clue how to get around this or if I am doing something wrong. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A template match of `/` does not start at the document element, it is the "root node" - which is before any content. The first node() in the document doesn't have to be the document element, it could be a comment or a processing instruction and would be a child of the "root node".

So, if you want to match the document element `mods`, and you don't want to worry about namespaces your template match could be `/*`. Then your XPath selecting elements relative from the document element would work.

However, your `titleInfo` and `title` elements inherit the namespace of the document element. So, if you want to match them you have several options:

1. Declare the namespace and give it a prefix so that you can use it in your XPath
2. Match generically on element with a predicate filter to match the local-name() and namespace-uri() - but if you know the URI it would be easier to declare it and use the prefix in option #1.
3. Match generically on element with a predicate filter to match just the local-name(). Not as clean/proper, but likely will work.
4. Match generically on element for each step and rely on the structure of this simple document to find the element you are looking for

**Option #1:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:m="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3">
        <xsl:template match="/m:mods">
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="m:titleInfo/m:title"/></p>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Option #2:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='mods' and namespace-uri()='http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3']">
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p>Hello</p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='titleInfo' 
                                   and namespace-uri()='http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3']/*[local-name()='title' and namespace-uri()='http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3']"/></p>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Option #3:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='mods']">
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p>Hello</p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='titleInfo']/*[local-name()='title']"/></p>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Option #4:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="*/*"/></p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a prefixed declaration for your namespace and then match on the prefixed names.

Below is untested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:loc="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" exclude-result-prefixes="loc">
<xsl:template match="/loc:mods">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="loc:titleInfo/loc:title"/></p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```